How to add a segment to an Excel radar plot
I have the following radar plot:

I want to highlight the category segments to the plot like so:

The hacky way I did above is by showing an image in the background, but I am hoping there is a way to do it within Excel.

You may try following steps:
Add one column, such as "Count", after "Weight" column.

Select the data range, click Insert > Recommended Charts > All Charts tab > Combo, then select Radar chart for "Weight", Pie chart for "Count", click OK.

Right-click on this chart, choose "Select Data". Select the correct data source for "Weight" and "Count".

In may sample, for "Weight", the Category source is =Sheet1!$B$2:$B$11. For "Count", the Category source is =Sheet1!$A$15:$A$16, the Series source is =Sheet1!$B$15:$B$16.

At last, please change the format to your needs, such as change the radar line color.

